# JQuery - .val() return old value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a some trouble, i use 
https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck

with this function

```
                $('#email').on('keypress', function(event) {
                $(this).mailcheck({
                    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
                        $('#email_check').html("Did you mean <b><i><a href='#' id='suggest_email'>" + suggestion.full + "</a></b></i>?");
                        $('#suggest_email').on('click', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#email').val($(this).text());
                            $('#email_check').empty();
                            $('.error_js').empty()
                        });
                    },
                    empty: function(element) {
                        $('#email_check').empty();
                        $('.error_js').empty()
                    }
                });
            });
```

But when the script use :

```
opts.email = this.val();
```

(line 263 of this file https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck/blob/master/src/mailcheck.js )

this.val() return the old value of my input.
i've tried to use a

```
this.attr("value");
```

and

```
this.prop("value");
```

Same problem.

When i do a console.log(this); and look for the value of my input, in the object, it's good, it contain the good value.

How to get the proper value then ?
That's why i request your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use the `keypress` event because it is fired before the new `value` or `character` is registered in the `input`. Use [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead

```
$('#email').on('keyup', function(event) {
                $(this).mailcheck({
                    suggested: function(element, suggestion) {
                        $('#email_check').html("Did you mean <b><i><a href='#' id='suggest_email'>" + suggestion.full + "</a></b></i>?");
                        $('#suggest_email').on('click', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#email').val($(this).text());
                            $('#email_check').empty();
                            $('.error_js').empty()
                        });
                    },
                    empty: function(element) {
                        $('#email_check').empty();
                        $('.error_js').empty()
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: :o thank you've got it right :D just try it and that's work, thanks

Comment: @kaldoran, dont forget to mark the most helpful answer as accepted to guide future readers of this post

Comment: I forgot to do it :p thanks ;)
( i've tried before but there is a timer on, we cant mark the most helpful answer before 15 min )

Answer (score 1):

The console log object show the object properties at the time the object was first expanded, so in your case the value is not yet being set when the keypress event triggers, but when you read it later in the console, it's set. To see the actual current state of the object property, **log that property only instead of the whole object**.

The keyup event should work fine instead.